# Search and replace image textures in a project?

Tags: texturing, materials

Is there a way to search though the materials in a Blender project and replace the texture names?

For example, I have a PBR material consisting of several different external textures and I want to change the names of the textures while leaving the shader nodes intact. Rather than clicking on each texture node and loading a new texture, I'm hoping there's a way to search and replace the texture names. Seems to me this should be possible; is it? Thanks. Blender 3.0, Windows 11

Comment: There is no built-in to do this, but you could easily adapt [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245500/42221) to do the image replacement when it finds an image node.

Comment: Marty Fouts, thank you for the suggestion. I'm not a scripting expert so I'll need to do some research to see if this will meet my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to make a list of pairs of images, with the old name in the new.  In the if statement where I print the image name, you need to replace the print with code to do the change.  You can find a sample of that code in other answers here.